# Show hexadecimal dump of string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, unicode, hex

Is there any way to obtain an hexadecimal dump of a string in SQL Server? It'd be useful to troubleshoot character set and collation issues.

In MySQL you'd do `SELECT HEX('€uro')` and in Oracle you'd do `SELECT DUMP('€uro') FROM DUAL`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST('€uro' AS VARBINARY(4))
```

Returns

```
  0x8075726F
```

On my default collation.

**Edit.** 
Just noticed the Unicode tag

```
SELECT CAST(N'€uro' AS VARBINARY(8))
```

Returns

```
 0xAC20750072006F00
```

Comment: Lovely! Do you know what the byte order depends on? Being picky, I'd prefer `20AC` rather than `AC20`, but in any case I want to make sure what order to expect.

Comment: @Álvaro - No I don't know the answer to that I'm afraid.

Comment: @Álvaro: This is a bit wicked, and I suppose it could fail for strings that use higher-plane Unicode glyphs, but it seems to meet your byte-order requirement:

SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(0xFEFF + SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(@v as XML) as VARBINARY(MAX)),3,DATALENGTH(CAST(@v as XML))-2) AS XML) AS VARBINARY(MAX)),3,DATALENGTH(CAST(@v as XML))-2)