# SQL query not returning record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, where-clause

I am trying to retrieve a record from a table with a given field value.  The query is:

```
declare @imei varchar(50)
set @imei = 'ee262b57-ccb4-4a2b-8410-6d8621fd9328'

select *
from tblDevices
where imei = @imei
```

which returns nothing.

If I comment out the where clause all records are returned, including the one I am looking for.  The value is clearly in the table field and matches exactly, but I cannot get the where clause to work.

I literally copied the value out of the table to ensure it was correct.

I would appreciate any guidance on my mistake.

**Table def:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDevices](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [create_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [update_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [other_id] [int] NULL,
    [description] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [authorized] [int] NOT NULL,
    [imei] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblDevices] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Edit**

Using user2864740 suggestion, I queried the following:

```
select hashbytes('SHA1', imei) as h1 from tblDevices where id =8

returns:
0x43F9067C174B2F2F2C0FFD17B9AC7F54B3C630A2

select hashbytes('SHA1', @imei) as h2

returns:
0xB9B82BB440B04729B2829B335E6D6B450572D2AB
```

So, I am not sure what this means.  My poor little brain is having a hard time understanding that A <> A?!  What is going on here if it's not a collation issue?  How can two identical values not be considered equal?

**Edit 2**

this is the table record I want:

```
8           2013-10-22 12:43:10.223 2013-10-22 12:43:10.223 -1                                                         1           ee262b57-ccb4-4a2b-8410-6d8621fd9328
```

Comment: Does imei and @imei have same data type ? for example nvarchar or varchar ?

Comment: Did you try using `like` instead of = ?

Comment: Yes I tried `Like`, I wrapped @imei with `LTRIM` and `RTRIM`.  None worked.

Comment: What's imei data type in tblDevices?

Comment: @user2864740  I have posted the table definition.  What would you suggest?

Comment: @AndroidAddict The data in the table is not as expected (could be extra junk characters, even) and the given value really does not exist.

Comment: What happens if you try to insert a new row with that value and then repeat the select query?
Also, I am wondering if the datatype shouldnt be uniqueidentifier rather than varchar (but I see it has that type in the table definition)

Comment: @user2864740 How do I reconcile the collation issue?  What should it be for the query to work?

Comment: Uh, there in my edited post.

Comment: You can update the question again to confirm it isn't collation.

Comment: @Kaf If it's not a collation issue, why does SQL Server not consider the two values equal?

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) with your table schema and some data including the troubled one.

Comment: @Kaf the fiddle tools does not appear to be working or, I don't understand how to use it.  I put my table def into the build schema text area but I don't appear to be able to do anything else with it.

Comment: Are you sure that the record is present? Have you checked whitespaces, etc.?

Comment: @Kaf, I don't think I am going to be able to get fiddle to work.  It's not responsive when I try to access it from my server (perhaps a firewall is blocking something).  And, it only appears to work with Internet Explorer.  I am on a Mac so that's not an option except via the server.

Comment: Try: select * from tblDevices
where  rtrim(ltrim(imei)) = @imei

Comment: @neutrino these things have already been tried.

Comment: But the fact is that the hash value of each string is not the same... Could you post the full record that is not being retrieved?

Comment: Maybe the collation? select *
from tblDevices
where imei collate database_default = @imei collate database_default

Comment: @neutrino Please see my post edit 2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39768/discussion-between-neutrino-and-android-addict)

Comment: As indicated by the result of the hash query, the data *is* different. I suspect that there is a pesky can't-see-me-whitespace or similar that is *lost* when copying the output. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734435/show-hexadecimal-dump-of-string/3734452#3734452 for a method go get the "hex dump" of the string, and see if that shows anything surprising.

Comment: @user2864740  I just confirmed that to be the case.  Performed a character count on each respectively.  Still not sure how the extra char (non-printable and non visible) got into the table, but am now trimming the input variable just to be sure I put in what I am expecting.  Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @AndroidAddict hi there can be characters in differenct ascii try function in this page http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx with your row from table and then with your variable. Compare numeric Ascii values of both strings...

Answer (score 0):

Kinda of taking a wild stab but with the two hashes showing they are in fact different, wondering if you just have an extra space somewhere Maybe try:

```
select *
from tblDevices
where Trim(imei) = (@imei)
```

Comment: Not an extra space, that would have gotten captured when I copied the data out of the table field.  It was an unprintable, non-displayable character that somehow got into the field.  Still scratching my head on how that happened - but put countermeasures in to prevent future occurrences.

Comment: If you read the comments, you will notice those tricks have been covered - and incidentally did not remove the offending character.  :^)